# Starting a std::functional object in a thread, inside a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, c++17

I have a member function pointer and I'm trying to invoke the function in one of the member function. The function pointer is set using a lambda.

```
class CFoo
{
    std::function<void(int a, int b)> m_fFunc;

    public:

    CFoo() {}

    void Init()
    {
        m_fFunc = [](int a, int b)
        {
            printf("A : %d\tB %d\n", a, b);
        };
    }

    void Call(int a, int b)
    {
        std::thread th(&CFoo::m_fFunc, this, a, b);
        th.join();
    }
};

int main()
{

    CFoo foo;
    foo.Init();
    foo.Call(1, 2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
g++-9 -std=c++17 main.cpp -lpthread
In file included from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/thread: In instantiation of ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = std::function<void(int, int)> CFoo::*; _Args = {CFoo*, int, int}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’:
main.cpp:44:50:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/thread:120:44: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  120 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
      |                                            ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/thread: In instantiation of ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<std::function<void(int, int)> CFoo::*, CFoo*, int, int> >’:
/usr/include/c++/9/thread:131:22:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = std::function<void(int, int)> CFoo::*; _Args = {CFoo*, int, int}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’
main.cpp:44:50:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/thread:243:4: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<std::function<void(int, int)> CFoo::*, CFoo*, int, int> >::__result<std::tuple<std::function<void(int, int)> CFoo::*, CFoo*, int, int> >’
  243 |    _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Ind...>)
      |    ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/thread:247:2: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<std::function<void(int, int)> CFoo::*, CFoo*, int, int> >::__result<std::tuple<std::function<void(int, int)> CFoo::*, CFoo*, int, int> >’
  247 |  operator()()
      |  ^~~~~~~~
```

I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: why are you passing `this` to a `void(int a, int b)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that an `std::function` is not a member function,so you don't need to pass `this` or use the pointer-to-member syntax.

```
    void Call(int a, int b)
    {
        std::thread th(m_fFunc, a, b);
        th.join();
    }
```

If you wanted to call a member function directly, then you could do something like this:

```
    void Print(int a, int b)
    {
        printf("A : %d\tB %d\n", a, b);
    }
    void Call(int a, int b)
    {
        std::thread th(&CFoo::Print, this, a, b);
        th.join();
    }
```